# MongoDB count till date

Tags: php, mongodb

I would like to do a count query in MongoDB to count till a certain date (for example today); so it will count all the rows found till the 26th of may.

I have a variable with the date in ms, so I have to pass that through in the php query. Can someone help me out?

EDIT:

I have a database tweetdb, with one collection: testtweets. In testtweets, every row is a JSON formatted tweet with the date in line "created_at". Hope I'm clear enough.

Comment: Would be really helpful if you could use the [edit] link to include some sample documents to show your db structure.

Comment: Hope I made myself more clear now

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.

```
db.testtweets.find( { "created_at":{ $lte: ISODate("2016-05-26")}}).count()
```

Comment: Why not [count](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/) of mongodb?

Comment: Yes, we can also use db.collection.count(). It is equivalent to the db.collection.find(query).count() construct.

Comment: 2016-05-26T16:02:21.053+0200 E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) -- What have I done wrong?

Comment: Can you please post whole query?

Comment: Just ran your query: db.testtweets.find( { "created_at":{ $lte: ISODate("2016-05-26"))}}).count()

Comment: Please try this : db.testtweets.find( { "created_at":{ $lte: ISODate("2016-05-26T22:00:00Z"))}}).count()

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113132/discussion-between-sandesh-and-joost).

Answer (score 1):

in continuation with @Sandesh's answer. you could also do

```
 db.testtweets.count( { "created_at":{ $lte: ISODate("2016-05-26")}})
```

if 26th inclusive, use $lte. else just $lt

p.s: if you have sharded cluster db.count() may return inaccurate results. 
then db..find().count() is preferred. below link explains in more detail
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/#sharded-clusters

Comment: db.testtweets.count( { "created_at":{ $lte: ISODate("2016-05-26"))}}) Can you help me out with this error?

Comment: just corrected my query. sorry about that. there was an extra brace in it. try now?

Comment: The query runs without error now, but it does not work as hoped :(. Get 0 back, while its probably 200k or something. Date notation in the collection is as following: created_at: Fri Apr 01 16:32:09 +0000 2016

Comment: if i understand correctly, date is not saved in isodate format? if you could post a sample entry in your collection (specifically date part) that would be helpful

Comment: Indeed, when I export all dates to a file its showed as following: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ab3587e5b1f3d78036e7e57fec182005

Comment: thank you. (just saw) have you stored this in date or string format? if latter above query won't work

Comment: since it looks like you are saving it as string, you might have to do something like this. helps?                                                                                                          var cursor = db.query.find({query:23}) (query by something)
 var d = cursor.next()
 db.query.update({query:23},{"$set":{"date":new Date(d.date)}})

 db.query.find({"query":23})
 "_id" : ObjectId("57483ad982f756da715dfb11"), "query" : 23, "date" : ISODate("2016-04-01T16:32:09Z") }

Comment: but if you've more than one row to update you will have to add while loop before cursor.next(). or Convert it to isodate before you populate testtweets

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mongodb-count](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/) and [$lte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/) or [$lt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/) to get the counts of the records created before 26/05/1026.

```
db.testtweets.count( 
    { 
        "created_at":{ $lte: new Date("2016-05-26")}
    }
)
```

Comment: 2016-05-27T12:59:31.084+0200 E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Comment: My bad! An extra ')' was there in the query. Updated the answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
db.<collection name>.find({
    "created_at": {
        $lte: ISODate("2016-05-25T03:08:20Z")
    }
}).count();
```

Please check this query.